# Site visualization problem with Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser, webpage-rendering

I have a site based on Solar Sentinel Joomla template: [www.sism.org](http://www.sism.org)

I'm having some visualization problem with chrome.

The right side-bar is shifted down after all the content, while it should be floating on the right!

Could someone explain me why?

PS: the template css is pretty messy, and there is some custom css and js made by me inline at the beginning of the page.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML is throwing a lot of validation errors: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sism.org%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

My guess is that Safari and Firefox are rendering around these errors in a way that is according to what you would expect. Try fixing the errors and seeing what happens. If nothing else, you'll have ruled out invalid HTML as the issue.

Comment: i wish i could rule out this template... thanks i will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `div class="col3"` is inside your `div class="colright"`.

Try placing `div class="col3"` outside the other one.

Comment: but that doesn't explain why i don't see this problem in safari and FF!